# A lifetime issue pops up after a seemingly ineffectual change

Tags: rust

```
#![allow(dead_code)]
#![allow(unused_variables)]

use std::cell::Cell;

pub struct Foo<'a> {
    pub x1: &'a i32,
    pub x2: &'a i32,
    pub data: Cell<&'a i32>,
}

fn test<'a>(foo: &Foo<'a>) {
    let x1 = 1;
    let data = Cell::new(foo.data.get());
    // UNCOMMENT THE NEXT LINE
    // let data = foo.data.clone();
    Foo {
        x1: &x1,
        x2: foo.x2,
        data,
    };
}
```

The above code compiles, but if you uncomment the line I marked in the code (and optionally comment out the line before it), you will see the following error (I use Rust 1.58.1):

```
error[E0597]: `x1` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:18:13
   |
12 | fn test<'a>(foo: &Foo<'a>) {
   |         -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
18 |         x1: &x1,
   |             ^^^
   |             |
   |             borrowed value does not live long enough
   |             this usage requires that `x1` is borrowed for `'a`
...
22 | }
   | - `x1` dropped here while still borrowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
```

The line that causes error when uncommented strongly seems to have the same effect as the line before it - I basically inlined the clone implementation; quote from the rust stdlib source:

```
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
impl<T: Copy> Clone for Cell<T> {
    #[inline]
    fn clone(&self) -> Cell<T> {
        Cell::new(self.get())
    }
}
```

Question: where the difference comes from?

Comment: There is a difference, but I'm not sure why it matters yet. `Cell::new(foo.data.get())` has type `Cell<&i32>`, but `foo.data.clone()` has type `Cell<&'a i32>`.

Comment: @cdhowie: uff, good catch. With `foo.data.clone()` the `Foo` constructed in `test` is forced to have type `Foo<'a>`, for which `x1` doesn't live long enough. `Cell::new` allows rust to pick a new lifetime for `Cell<&i32>`, which it correctly picks to be short enough for `x1`.

Comment: @Caesar Yeah, I figured that out a bit ago but am having trouble coming up with Rust code that succinctly and clearly illustrates what's going on. The biggest giveaway is that even with the "good" version of the code, you can force the error by changing `Foo` to `Foo::<'a>` where the instance is constructed, forcing the lifetime yourself. The part that's still a bit confusing to me is that I thought Rust would pick the _shortest_ lifetime when the lifetime was inferred, but instead, here, it seems to be picking the longest (from `data`) instead of the shortest (from `&x1`).

Comment: I expect that the lifetime being part of a generic type argument is disallowing the compiler from choosing a shorter lifetime, but I don't know enough about the Rust specification to say for sure.

Comment: I believe I now understand the reason, but this looks like a usability issue anyway. The code I gave is an example of how the to-be-only copying abstraction in the language leaks making you hack around on a simple and legitimate use case. This boils down to: in general, you might have to manually inline some cloning code, and hope it doesn't depend on private stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write

```rust
    let data = Cell::new(foo.data.get());
```

the value `foo.data.get()` has type `&'a i32`. This reference can then be implicitly reinterpreted as having any lifetime *no longer than* `'a`. In particular, we can take it as the lifetime I'll call `'f`, an actually-unnameable lifetime which is outlived by `'a` and the scope of the local `x1`. Then we call `Cell::new` to construct a local `Foo<'f>`.

On the other hand, if `data` is a clone of `data` from `Foo`, then `data` must have the exact type `Cell<&'a i32>`, and because `Cell` is interior mutable, its type parameter is [invariant](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html), so the `Cell<&'a i32>` cannot be reinterpreted as containing a reference with a shorter lifetime, and so the `Foo` must be `Foo<'a>` — but `x` does not outlive `'a` so `&x1` cannot be stored in the `Foo<'a>`.

---

You write that you “inlined the clone implementation”, and wonder why this makes a difference; the key differences are that the inlined version

1. is *aware that it is dealing with a shared reference*, rather than an opaque `T` in `Cell<T>` (so it can use shortening/reborrowing/covariance), and
2. does not force the input and output to be the same type (including lifetimes).

To illustrate this, here's a rewritten version with two functions with identical bodies, but different signatures. This compiles, but if you substitute `clone_cell` for `rebuild_cell` it won't compile.

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;

// Type inside the Cell is opaque and will remain unchanged.
fn clone_cell<T: Copy>(cell: &Cell<T>) -> Cell<T> {
    Cell::new(cell.get())
}

// Input and output lifetimes are separated, and have a relationship
// but are not necessarily equal.
fn rebuild_cell<'input, 'output>(cell: &Cell<&'input i32>) -> Cell<&'output i32>
where
    'input: 'output
{
    // When the data flows from cell.get() to Cell::new(), the compiler 
    // notices that the shared reference can be coerced from &'input i32
    // to &'output i32. Thus, 'output is allowed to be shorter, to satisfy
    // any other lifetime requirement imposed on the output cell.
    Cell::new(cell.get())
}

fn test<'a>(foo: &[Cell<&'a i32>; 2]) {
    let x1 = 1;
    let _ = [rebuild_cell(&foo[0]), Cell::new(&x1)];
}
```

---

Even in common uses of the standard library, `Clone::clone` does not always have the signature one would like; for example, the [`ToOwned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html) trait exists to allow a change of type. Unfortunately, there's no general way to apply that technique to problems like this, since there's no way to express “allow the lifetimes anywhere in this type to become flexible” as a trait signature.